# set uses permissions to launch application within another application

Tags: android, permissions

How can I set uses permissions or which permission I need to launch an application within another application. I want to launch my second app with a button in first app

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but I think this might help you get started: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: I want to run my app within another app, what permission needed to be add to manifest file ?

Comment: None.  Permissions are not involved.  But the Activity you want to run does need to have an Intent filter in the manifest.